# How can I add an accelerator key to an MFC checkbox in the designer?

Tags: mfc

Is there a way to add an accelerator button to an MFC checkbox in the designer, or does it have to be done in code?  All of the examples I found on the web show how to do it in code.  I tried adding an ampersand to the caption, but the expected underscore did not appear.

Comment: If you put an ampersand `&` in front of one of the letters in the label, you can use alt-letter as an accelerator.

Comment: I tried putting the ampersand in, but the underscore did not appear.  My apologies for not mentioning that in the original post.  I will add it.

Comment: The underscore only appears when you hold down the Alt key.